# error when using universalimageloader

Tags: android, android-view, android-library

I found a bug in my application and I can not fix it. I use SwipeRefreshLayout and he helped discover a bug. when I'm on a fragment of a list and try to update SwipeRefreshLayout and if this time I go to another fragment of the application will take off.

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder.<init>(ImageLoaderConfiguration.java:196)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ImageLoaderConfiguration.java:127)
            at com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle.fragments.adapters.EmployeeListAdapter.<init>(EmployeeListAdapter.java:52)
            at com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle.fragments.EmployeessList$1.onPostExecute(EmployeessList.java:109)
            at com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle.fragments.EmployeessList$1.onPostExecute(EmployeessList.java:69)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I just use the library `ImageLoader` which is initialized in the constructor of the fragment:

which is initialized in the constructor of the adapter:

```
public class EmployeeListAdapter extends SectionedBaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> sections;
    private ArrayList<List<EmployeesListBean>> employees;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
    private Context context;

    public EmployeeListAdapter(ArrayList<EmployeesListBean> employeesListBeans, Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        Map<String, List<EmployeesListBean>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (EmployeesListBean employeesListBean : employeesListBeans) {
            if (!map.containsKey(employeesListBean.getDepart_name()))
                map.put(employeesListBean.getDepart_name(), new ArrayList<EmployeesListBean>());
            map.get(employeesListBean.getDepart_name()).add(employeesListBean);
        }
        sections = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        employees = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
    }
```

error points to a string:

```
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
```

please tell me what I'm doing wrong? initialization may need to do elsewhere?

EDITE MY FRAGMENT(FULL):

```
public class EmployeessList extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private String link;
    private PinnedHeaderListView listView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.employeelist, null);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_employe_list);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        listView = (PinnedHeaderListView) v.findViewById(R.id.pinnedListView);
        link=getArguments().getString(MyActivity.ARGUMENT_LINK);
        if (InternetResiver.isOnline(getActivity())) {
            progressDialog = MyProgress.getProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.show();
           setData();
        } else {
            AlertDialog alert = InternetResiver.getAlertDialog(getActivity());
            alert.show();
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        if (InternetResiver.isOnline(getActivity())) {
          setData();
        } else {
            AlertDialog alert = InternetResiver.getAlertDialog(getActivity());
            alert.show();
        }
    }

    public void setData(){


        new MyAsincTask(getActivity()){
            int city = 0;
            int holiday = 0;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
                super.onPostExecute(document);
                ArrayList<EmployeesListBean> employeesListBeans = new ArrayList<>();
                Elements elementsUid = document.select("uid");
                Elements elementsStaffName = document.select("staff_name");
                Elements elementsDepartName = document.select("depart_name");
                Elements elementsLocation = document.select("location");
                Elements elementsInTime = document.select("in_time");
                Elements elementsOutTime = document.select("out_time");
                Elements elementsLateness = document.select("lateness");
                Elements elementsPhoto = document.select("photo");

                for (int i = 0; i < elementsUid.size(); i++) {
                    EmployeesListBean employeesListBean = new EmployeesListBean();
                    employeesListBean.setUid(elementsUid.get(i).ownText());
                    employeesListBean.setStaff_name(elementsStaffName.get(i).ownText());
                    employeesListBean.setDepart_name(elementsDepartName.get(i).ownText());
                    employeesListBean.setLocation(elementsLocation.get(i).ownText());
                    employeesListBean.setIn_time(elementsInTime.get(i).ownText());
                    employeesListBean.setOut_time(elementsOutTime.get(i).ownText());
                    employeesListBean.setLateness(elementsLateness.get(i).ownText());
                    employeesListBean.setPhoto(elementsPhoto.get(i).ownText());

                    employeesListBeans.add(employeesListBean);

                    if (employeesListBeans.get(i).getOut_time().equals("на смене") && elementsLocation.get(i).ownText().equals("city")) {
                        city += 1;
                    }
                    if(employeesListBeans.get(i).getOut_time().equals("на смене") && elementsLocation.get(i).ownText().equals("holiday")){
                        holiday += 1;
                    }
                }
                EmployeeListAdapter sectionedAdapter = new EmployeeListAdapter(employeesListBeans, getActivity());
                listView.setAdapter(sectionedAdapter);
                progressDialog.cancel();
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                getActivity().setTitle("Сотрудники(city:" + city + ",holiday:" + holiday + ")");
            }
        }.execute(link);
    }
}
```

MY ADAPTER(FULL):

```
public class EmployeeListAdapter extends SectionedBaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> sections;
    private ArrayList<List<EmployeesListBean>> employees;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
    private Context context;

    public EmployeeListAdapter(ArrayList<EmployeesListBean> employeesListBeans, Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        Map<String, List<EmployeesListBean>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (EmployeesListBean employeesListBean : employeesListBeans) {
            if (!map.containsKey(employeesListBean.getDepart_name()))
                map.put(employeesListBean.getDepart_name(), new ArrayList<EmployeesListBean>());
            map.get(employeesListBean.getDepart_name()).add(employeesListBean);
        }
        sections = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        employees = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int section, int position) {
        return employees.get(section).get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int section, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionCount() {
        return sections.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCountForSection(int section) {
        return employees.get(section).size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(int section, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout layout;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.itememploee, null);
        } else {
            layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.staff_name_text)).setText(employees.get(section).get(position).getStaff_name());
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.depart_name_text)).setText("Должность: " + employees.get(section).get(position).getDepart_name());
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.location_text)).setText("Отель: " + employees.get(section).get(position).getLocation());
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.in_time_text)).setText("Пришел: " + employees.get(section).get(position).getIn_time());
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.out_time_text)).setText("Ушел: " + employees.get(section).get(position).getOut_time());
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lateness_text)).setText("Опоздание: " + employees.get(section).get(position).getLateness());
        imageLoader.displayImage(employees.get(section).get(position).getPhoto(), (CircleImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.employeePhoto), options, animateFirstListener);
        if (employees.get(section).get(position).getOut_time().equals("на смене")) {
            layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.employe_positive));
        }else{
            layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.employe_negative));
        }
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout layout;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.header_item_employee, null);
        } else {
            layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textItem)).setText(sections.get(section));
        return layout;
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your fragment code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always a good idea to have a look at the source code for your open source library :).

Code is here (I am assuming you're using the latest version):
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoaderConfiguration.java

The line in question:

```
195         public Builder(Context context) { 
196             this.context = context.getApplicationContext(); 
197         }
```

This means the context is null. Have a look at your adapter and see if that's indeed the case.

Additionally, and very important to note, you only need to initialize the image loader *once* not every time you're using it. Do it in your main launcher activity or better yet, in your application class (as long as you've overridden it in your manifest). If you need to override the default options, every method has an override that allows you to specify the loading options.

**Update:**

To create an application class, follow this tutorial:http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android

Then in the onCreate() method of the application class, initialize your ImageLoader by calling the init() method. Do not do this in a transitional class (your adapter). The Application class has access to the ApplicationContext which is what you need to be passing to the init() method.

**Update2:**

As per https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup you can initialize it in your main activity if you prefer.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this config
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
        ...
        .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    ...
    }
}
```

To get an instance of the image loader **anywhere** in your app, simply use the singleton instance by calling `ImageLoader.getInstance()`

Comment: what you have written nearer to the truth. could set an example or tell me where and what to add? because I myself still can not figure out

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: I just think that the use of application class can lead to other problems. for example in the notification. When you run through intent

Comment: I do not know how to create it. and then how to access imageLoader. And can it be done in the main Activity instead  application class?

Comment: Thanks this helped! And as I thought it was not the main cause of my problem ((((But there is another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

do this

```
private ImageLoader imageLoader ;

constructor(){

   DisplayImageOptions defaultDisplayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true).build();



    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultDisplayImageOptions);

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();

    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);


}
```

Comment: edited answer try this. more over you can shift this configuration to ApplicationController that extends Application . Other wise UIL will give you warnings

Comment: I do not understand the difference between your code from mine, krotoem the fact that you have added ImageLoaderConfiguration. I installed by default.
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

Comment: iamgeLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); it is not properly vet

Comment: yup its for ref to have image loader after that. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way in your constructor:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
//do whatever you want
.writeDebugLogs()
.build();

imageLoader.init(config);
```